# Could we make it easier for reviewers of suggested edits to point out strategies for improving or participating more meaningfully?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

I have recently learned that it is *frequently* a problem that people will find a tag that needs some cleanup and do the cleanup without making other edits to the post. **If it is actually a common problem, could we make it easier for reviewers of suggested edits to select a reason for rejection that also includes advice on a strategy to use instead?**

My understanding is that the problem is that it is not desirable for newer users with less reputation to gain reputation points by doing these edits. But, as a newcomer, I had no idea that there was another option: namely, requesting a tag cleanup so that people who don't get points for their edits would be able to fix the problems.

This post is not about whether or not it is a real problem for people to earn reputation by making minor edits or by retagging. For me, the real issue is that the rejections of my suggested edits came with reasons that would not have been helpful in shaping my behavior on the site without a lot of effort on my part. The desired behavior or requesting a tag cleanup did not come from a rejection comment, but it seemed like something that users who can edit *know* about that that others *don't know* about. I only found out the option exists because I asked a question to try to clarify what was happening on the meta site.

Maybe something like:
"This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post."

Could be combined with:
"It looks like you are trying to edit just the tags of this post. If you are concerned about a tag that may be being misused, please suggest a tag cleanup on meta as a discussion."